# Core Data Update in the AppStore

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, core-data-migration

I am just about to update one application from me. This app uses Core Data for saving the data, which the user puts in.

Now I want to fix some bugs, which aren't associated with Core Data at all.

What do I have to do that the User gets his data after downloading the Update?
I don't think about Lightweight Migration, because I haven't changed anything.
Do I have to add a new Model Versioning File? - I don't know.

Comment: Why would you do new model version if your fix is not associated with CoreDate?

Comment: I thought of maybe Core Data will be overwritten... but this was shit- I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to to anything. If the model and the data is not updated as part of the update, and you are storing the user's data in the documents directory, then a new version of your app will just carry on using the existing data.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed your Core Data schema at all, then you don't have to do anything. It'll still read the old data files with no problem.